# No se cargan los datos de un INSERT realizado con PHP y MSQLI pero no me muestra ningun error

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mysqli, modal

Estoy intentando migrar un codigo funcional de un sistema antiguo a un nuevo sistema con un formulario mas moderno y atractivo realizado con ventanas modales pero no logro realizar la insercion de datos, y lo mas raro es que al darle clic al input de guardar el form se cierra y no muestra ningun error aparente pero tampoco se cargan los datos en el formulario. Ya nose donde mas buscar, no le encuentro la logica, las consultas estan bien, la conexion se realiza, los datos son validos. Será posible que el prblema se deba a que los form se cargan en una ventana modal? si talvez suena muy mal esa teoria pero ya es producto de mi desesperacion.

```js
<?php //require_once('../Connections/conex.php')
include ("../Connections/conex.php")?>

<?php
   if(isset($_POST['add']))
   {
    $nombre       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,(strip_tags($_POST["nombre"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
    $apellido       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,(strip_tags($_POST["apellido"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
    $estado       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,(strip_tags($_POST["estado"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres
    $fecha  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,(strip_tags($_POST["fecha"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
    $rol  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,(strip_tags($_POST["rol"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
    $sexo      = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,(strip_tags($_POST["sexo"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
    $usuario   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,(strip_tags($_POST["usuario"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
    $pass1   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,(strip_tags($_POST["pass2"],ENT_QUOTES)));//Escanpando caracteres 
    
    
   

    $cek = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT usuario FROM login WHERE usuario='$usuario'");//verificar si el usuario existe
    if(mysqli_num_rows($cek) == 0)
    {
      $insert = mysqli_query($conex, "INSERT INTO login (nombre, apellido, estado, fecha, sexo, usuario, password ,rol, foto)
       VALUES('$nombre', '$apellido',$estado,'$fecha' ,$sexo, '$usuario','$pass1', $rol ,'usuario.png')"); or die(mysqli_error($conex));


      if($insert)
        {
       echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Bien hecho! Los datos han sido guardados con éxito.</div>';
        }
      else
       {
       echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>Error. No se pudo guardar los datos !</div>';
       }
      
    }
   }
?>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" align="center">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo usuario</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<form data-smk-icon="glyphicon-remove" action="" method="post">


<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2"><label class="control-label">Nombre</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
    <input class="form-control" name="nombre"
    placeholder="Nombre" required maxlength="25" >
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2"><label class="control-label">Apellido</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
    <input class="form-control" name="apellido"
    placeholder="Apellido" required maxlength="25" >
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2"><label class="control-label">Estado</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
<select class="form-control" name="estado" required>
     <option value="1" selected>Activo</option>
          <option value="0">Inactivo</option>
        </select>      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-4"><label class="control-label">Fecha Nacimiento</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="date" class="form-control"  name="fecha" required>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2"><label class="control-label">Sexo</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="sexo" required>
          <option value="" >--Seleccione--</option>
     <option value="0" >Hombre</option>
          <option value="1" >Mujer</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2"><label class="control-label">Usuario</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="usuario"
    placeholder="Usuario" required maxlength="10" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2"><label class="control-label">Password</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
         <div class="input-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" data-smk-strongPass="medium" maxlength="15"
      name="pass1" required >
      <span class="input-group-addon">medium</span>
    </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>      
<br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-4"><label class="control-label">Repetir Password</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
           <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass2" maxlength="15" >
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2"><label class="control-label">Rol</label></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="rol" required style="width: 100%;">
          <option value="0" selected>Usuario</option>
          <option value="1">Administrador</option>
        </select>  
      </div>
  </div>
</div>         
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Guardar datos">
            
            <a href="usuario.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancelar</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu botón es de tipo submit entonces debería haber un `form action = tuphp.php` lo tienes? O cómo haces el llamada al PHP? Con jQuery?

Comment: coloque el action= "../php/añadirusuario.php" y cuando presiono el input me redirecciona a "localhost/añadirusuario.php" y obviamente no encontrará la pagina. Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Esa es la ruta correcta? No deberías usar la `ñ` ni tildes en los nombres de archivos.

Comment: Si verifique la ruta, el archivo del form esta en una carpeta html saliendo de esa carpeta esta la carpeta php, y dentro de la carpeta está el archivo, le cambie el nombre a agg_usuario.php para verificar lo de la letra ñ y sigue comportandose igual.

Answer (score 0):

El action de tu formulario en el html está vacio, tendras que ponerle la ruta de tu index ahi mismo, si te lanza error 404 es porque el archivo no se encuentra en esa ruta, fijate si lo tenes dentro de una carpeta a añadir usuario

Comment: Cuando dices "controlador" te refieres al codigo php?? el sistema cuenta con un index que carga las ventanas modales con ajax y el codigo php es externo, pero si coloco el action= "ruta/añadiruser.php" me redirecciona al localhost/añadiruser.php y obvio "error 404 not found" Que hago mal?

Answer (score 0):

Como recomendación, fijate que tipo de campo estas insertando si es texto o número, muchas veces por mas que sea numero si lo pones con las comillas simples te ahorras dolores de cabeza.

No utilices caracteres especiales en los nombres de archivos.

Comment: en todos use comillas simples en el insert :D tampoco uso caracteres especiales en los nombres de archivos, pero al colocar el accion en el form el input se comporta mal, me redirecciona a: localhost/php/agg_usuario.php cuando deberia mandarme a localhost/sistema/php/agg_usuario.php. Sabes de casualidad porque se comporta asi?

Comment: fijate el uso de la ruta que estas poniendo tal vez te sea facil el uso de "/sistema/php/agg_usuario.php" en el action del form...

Comment: no pongas "../" porque eso te retorna una carpeta hacia atras desde donde estas ubicado... con "/" empezas desde el directorio raiz

Comment: Lo hice "/php/archivo.php" y cuando acciono el input este se va localhost/php/archivo.php" y sale el error 404 no entiendo porque se sale de la carpeta del sistema.

Comment: pone en el action `/sistema/php/archivo.php` o el archivo que necesites